# Authentication for the database which already have form authentication - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, open-source, asp.net-membership, asp.net-3.5

I have a database which has form authentication tables for an website [let say website A], now I have attached a new website [Website B] to the same database, in this website [Website B] also I have to provide login/authentication which would be separate from the website A authentication system. So I want to have separate table for the users of new website. Specification:

1. Website B will not have more than 5
   users
2. Hashing/Salting of password is
   required
3. Few columns required.

Suggest me how can I achieve it?

will there be any open source membership provider like we have .NET membership provider [form authentication].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the hashed password in the web.config file and than can read it. This is not one of the best approach but will work for you. To store information for 5 User is not going to consume space in Web.Config file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using .NET Forms authentication already, you could use a different "Application Name" in the Membership Provider settings for the second application and it will maintain two sets of users for you.

Comment: I suggested the same to my client but they are not satisfied with solution. They are ready with some more tables but different from the form authentication tables.

Comment: Youw ill have to build your own custom implementation then.  If they are for the same company, I'd be inclined to see the business need for separation.

Comment: I'd really like to know why they wouldn't be satisfied with this - it's a canned solution being used all over the world that "just works".  It's far less likely to have problems than anything custom you'd write.  Having said that, you could install the membership tables into a brand new SQL database and point the web.config to it instead.

Comment: @Greg I said the same to my client, even though I showed the demo and showed them that instead of creating another membership system for new site only for one user, it is better to keep one user in the membership table in the database... alas, they still don't want it..  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/how-to-handle-demanding-clients/5444#5444 This link can define my state of frustration

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: I love clients that give blanket statements and refuse to listen to reason, but what can you do?  You can deploy the mdf file directly with the application if they don't want to spin up an entirely new SQL Server database.